# Passing values between two c files of the same project in VC++

Tags: c, file, argument-passing

Well, I want to pass a string value from one file to another, how do I do that ? I don't want to save it to a text file and read it in the other one, I directly want to pass it to another c file .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like a function call?  A definition?  Copy and paste in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe just a #define MY_STR "your value" will do the job.

just create a .h file and include in both your C files

```
#ifndef _MY_HEADER_H
#define _MY_HEADER_H

#define MY_STR "your value"

#endif
```

then in your sources

```
#include "yourfile.h"
```

and use your MY_STR as a constant (please note that MY_STR will be a macro)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an `extern char commonstr[]` somewhere at the top (possibly in a header?) and a `char commonstr[LENGTH]` in one of the `.c` files. Then `commonstr` will be available throughout your project.

There is [an awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c) about extern variables in C.